# Can not manage to populate Edit Form with data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I checked many posts and I couldn't manage to solve my problem. What I want to do is, when I click to edit button, a form dialog appears. I want to populate that form with customer data. I can get data of row but I could not populate form with that data.

I have service, customer, customers and customer-list components. I created form in customer component. I want to edit a row in customer-list component because I have customer list in there. I can get elements in a row of the list as an object with populateForm(customer) function in customer.service, but I couldn't put them in the form.

customer.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  formData  : Customer;
  list : Customer[];

  readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:8085/api/auth'
  public _refreshNeeded$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }


  //PUT Request

  getCustomers(): Observable<Array<Customer>> {
    return this.http.get<CustomerModelResponse>(this.rootURL + '/customer',
      { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) })
      .pipe(map(x => x.content), catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  //Refresh after a successful POST Request

  get refreshNeeded$() {
    return this._refreshNeeded$;
  }

  //Insert Customer with POST Request

  postCustomer(formData: Customer) {
    return this.http
      .post(this.rootURL + '/customer', formData)
      .pipe(
        tap(()=>{
           this._refreshNeeded$.next();
         })
       );  
  }

  //PUT Request

  updateCustomer(formData : Customer){
    return this.http.put(this.rootURL+'/customer/'+formData.id, formData);   
  }

  //DELETE Request
  
  deleteCustomer(id : number){
    return this.http.delete<CustomerModelResponse>(this.rootURL+'/customer/'+id, 
    {headers : new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true','Content-Type':'application/json', 
                                'Authorization': '*',
                                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers'})})
    .pipe(map(x => x.content), catchError(this.handleError));
   }

  //Handle Error (is not elaborated!!!)

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      //client error
      console.log('client error: ' + error.error.message)
    } else {
      //backend error
      console.log(`backend error: ${error.status} error: ${error.error}`)
    }
    return throwError('Hata oluştu')
  }

  //Trying to populate form for Edit button
  /*populateForm(customer) {
    this.formData = Object.assign({}, customer); 
    console.log('Row clicked: ', customer); "test" not really part of function, works correctly!
  }*/
```

customer.component.ts

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  

  constructor(
    private service: CustomerService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private router: Router,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomerComponent>
  ) { }

  customerForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.submitCustomerForm()
  }

  submitCustomerForm() {
    this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: new FormControl(null),
      firstname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.email),
      customerId: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
    });
  }
  //Creating new form after refreshing list 

  initializedFormGroup() {
    this.customerForm.setValue({
      id: null,
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      email: '',
      customerId: null
    })
  }

  onClear() {
    this.customerForm.reset();
    this.initializedFormGroup();
  }
  
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.customerForm.valid) {
      this.service.postCustomer(this.customerForm.value).subscribe(res => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl(''))
      });
      this.customerForm.reset();
      this.initializedFormGroup();
      this.notificationService.success('İşleminiz tamamlanmıştır')
      this.onClose();
    }
  }

  onClose() {
    this.customerForm.reset();
    this.initializedFormGroup();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

customer-list.component.ts

```
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {

  customerData: any = [];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Customer>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'customerId', 'action'];
  searchKey: string;

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    public service: CustomerService,
    ) {
    this.service._refreshNeeded$.subscribe(() => {
      this.service.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
        this.customerData = data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>(this.customerData);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        }, 0);
      })
    })

    this.service.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
      this.customerData = data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>(this.customerData);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }, 0);
    })

  }


  ngOnInit() { }

  deleteCustomer(index: number, e) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      
      const data = this.dataSource.data;
      data.splice((this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize) + index, 1);
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      this.service.deleteCustomer(e.id).subscribe()
    }
  }


  onSearchClear() {
    this.searchKey = "";
    this.applyFilter();
  }

  applyFilter() {
    this.dataSource.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
  

  onEdit(element){
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    this.service.populateForm(element);
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "30%";
    this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
}
```

customer-list.html edit button section

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary"(click)="onEdit(element)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: Other than console.log() in `populateForm()` are you doing anything that can be posted here?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Well I tried something like `this.formData = Object.assign({}, customer);` or `this.formData.setValue(customer);` and but it didn't work. I guess formData nothing to do with my actual form in custormer component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling a method on a service(You can also do with service, but need to use BehaviorSubject), you can just set the `data` to dialogConfig like below

**customer-list.component.ts**

```
onEdit(element) {
  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  // this.service.populateForm(element);
  dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
  dialogConfig.width = "30%";
  dialogConfig.data = element;
  this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent, dialogConfig);
}

// or

onEdit(element) {
  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  // this.service.populateForm(element);
  this.dialog.open(CustomerComponent, {
    autoFocus : true,
    data : element,
    width : "30%",
  });
}
```

**customer.component.ts** and in the customer component, you need to inject dialog data like below

```
export class CustomerComponent {

  ...

  constructor(
    ...,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData, // `data` will contains the customer data and you can use it to `set` or `patch` the form
    ...
  ) {}

  ...

}
```

Comment: With your answer, I realized that I cannot find any DialogData to use, so I added`[(ngModel)]="service.formData.firstnameOrAnyInput"` to form fields in customer.component.html file, then populateForm()  fuction worked correctly.